# vb.net winforms datagridview how to tell where the user clicked in a cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, mouse, cell

I am adding a custom column to a custom datagridview.  One of the options this new datagridcolumn has is the ability show a value and then a button to allow the user to click on the button and something will happen.  The button only takes up the right portion of the cell and the rest is a value.  This button and value are displayable always and the button should always be able to be clicked on.  In datagridview's display mode the value and button are painted.  What I need help on is how to tell whether the user clicked on the button portion of the cell.  Can someone please provide example code on how to do this?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.  I just put some logic in the cellclick event of the datagridview to get the GetCellDisplayRectangle and converted that to screen points and got where the mouse is on the screen and did a bounds test with the rectangle contains method.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out.  I just put some logic in the cellclick event of the datagridview to get the GetCellDisplayRectangle and converted that to screen points and got where the mouse is on the screen and did a bounds test with the rectangle contains method.